# MongoDB aggregate with PHP - group by on date

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using an `aggregate` in `MongoDB` with `PHP`. The code looks like:

```
$results = $c->aggregate(array(
    array(
      '$project' => array(
          'day' => array('$dayOfYear' => '$executed')
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$group' => array(
          '_id' => array('day' => '$day'),
          'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$sort' => array(
          '_id' => 1
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$limit' => 30
    )
));
```

The problem with this, is that `$dayOfYear` does not sort correctly, because it sorts 2 then 3 then 345, 346... I need it to be date ascending. So, basically instead of simply doing `$dayOfYear` I need something like `$year-$month-$dayOfMonth`.

Unfortunately this does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can project those parts out and then group on them to enable you to group on the whole date:

```
$results = $c->aggregate(array(
    array(
      '$project' => array(
          'year' => array('$year' => '$executed' ),
          'month' => array('$month' => '$executed' ),
          'day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => '$executed')
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$group' => array(
          '_id' => array('year' => '$year', 'month' => '$month', 'day' => '$day'),
          'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$sort' => array(
          '_id.year' => 1,
          '_id.month' => 1,
          '_id.day' => 1
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$limit' => 30
    )
));
```

Something like that should do the trick allowing you to sort on, as you stated: `$year-$month-$dayOfMonth`.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Is there any way at the MongoDB level to include days with 0 rows. Basically I want to display the last 30 days, but the above returns 30 rows, but not the last 30 days.

Comment: @Justin Good question however not from what I know of yet due to relying on the rows date to actually fill in rows. I believe you will need to do this client side currently.

Comment: @Sammaye - i have suggested and edit in the above code. Your current code as it is .i.e. `'$sort' => ['_id' => 1]` would sort it only by day and would result in an order as follows - `1/10/2015 ,2/10/2015, 4/9/2015, 6/9/2015... and so on.`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't sort on the entire `_id` because you've set that up to contain an object (which can sort oddly), so change your `$sort` to this instead to specifically sort by day of year:

```
  '$sort' => array(
      '_id.day' => 1
  ),
```